# How update extensions using Microsoft Graph Client

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to update extensions via the Microsoft Graph Client. I have figured out how to add extensions using:

```
Dictionary<string, object> addData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
addData.Add("test", "data");
var ext = new OpenTypeExtension();
ext.ExtensionName = "TestData";
ext.AdditionalData = addData;
try
{
    graphClient.Users["usernameGoesHere"].Extensions.Request().AddAsync(ext).Wait();
}
```

But there appears to be a distinct lack of an update async call available under request. I am wondering if I am missing something. I am using Graph Client version Microsoft.Graph 1.4 and Microsoft.Graph.Core 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing one small detail.  You have to provide the extension identifier to get the correct request builder for updating an extension.

```cs
Dictionary<string, object> addData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
addData.Add("testUpdateKey", "dataUpdateValue");
var extPatchObject = new OpenTypeExtension();
extPatchObject.ExtensionName = "TestData";
extPatchObject.AdditionalData = addData;
try
{
    graphClient.Users["usernameGoesHere"].Extensions["TestData"].Request().UpdateAsync(extPatchObject).Wait();
}
```

Comment: I get access denied when running that for a group. I can create and get a group, but when I try and run the above for a group it doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave Do you have the [Group.ReadWrite.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0) permission in your access token? For your clicking convenience, http://jwt.ms/

Comment: I was actually trying to get this to work for a group, and I ended up having to use the guid not the group name as the index for the Groups collection.